# Compiling x86 and c with makefile

Tags: gcc, assembly, makefile, linker, gnu-assembler

I've been writing C for 2-3 years and recently picked up assembly but as I use Windows I've never needed to use make files before as I've just used Visual Studio. I'm trying to use Cygwin and an i686 cross compiler to compile c and assembly files, and then link them together into a binary file representing my operating system. I am new to make files so I don't know how to do this properly. This is what I've got so far for the `Makefile`:

```
CC = i686-elf-gcc
CC_FLAGS = -c -std=gnu99 -ffreestanding -O2 -Wall -Wextra -I./include
AS = i686-elf-as
LD = i686-elf-gcc -T linker.ld -o myos.bin
LD_FLAGS = -ffreestanding -O2 -nostdlib -lgcc
O_FILES = $(wildcard src/*.o)

all: $(O_FILES)
    $(LD) $(LD_FLAGS) $(O_FILES)

src/%.o: src/%.c
    $(CC) $(CC_FLAGS) -o $@ $<

src/%.o: src/%.asm
    $(AS) -o $@ $<
```

I'm getting an error stating that the linker can't find the entry symbol `_start` so obviously nothing is compiling. How would I fix this?

My `src/linker.ld` file that defines `_start` as the entry point is:

```
ENTRY(_start)

SECTIONS
{
        . = 1M;

        .text BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
        {
                *(.multiboot)
                *(.text)
        }

        .rodata BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
        {
                *(.rodata)
        }

        .data BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
        {
                *(.data)
        }

        .bss BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
        {
                *(COMMON)
                *(.bss)
        }
}
```

The `src/boot.asm`file I'm using that defines my `_start` label is:

```
# Declare constants for the multiboot header.
.set ALIGN,    1<<0             # align loaded modules on page boundaries
.set MEMINFO,  1<<1             # provide memory map
.set FLAGS,    ALIGN | MEMINFO  # this is the Multiboot 'flag' field
.set MAGIC,    0x1BADB002       # 'magic number' lets bootloader find the header
.set CHECKSUM, -(MAGIC + FLAGS) # checksum of above, to prove we are multiboot

.section .multiboot
.align 4
.long MAGIC
.long FLAGS
.long CHECKSUM

.section .bss
.align 16
stack_bottom:
.skip 16384 # 16 KiB
stack_top:

.section .text
.global _start
.type _start, @function
_start:
        mov $stack_top, %esp

        call kernel_main

        cli
1:      hlt
        jmp 1b

.size _start, . - _start
```

Comment: The error you are getting is a linker error. You don't show us your `linker.ld` but is sounds like you are using an entry point of `_start` but you have no `_start` label in your code.

Comment: _start is defined in boot.asm and here is linker.ld https://pastebin.com/MuJxLQW8

Comment: Can you show us your `boot.asm` . the problem is this isn't a minimal complete verifiable example. If you made your entire project available it would even e better.

Comment: I don't know of any decent websites to upload this to so here https://ufile.io/5c368
Everything compiles fine using the bash script which is why I think I have an error in the makefile

Comment: Are you compiling this under Windows? (I know you said you normally use Windows but not sure if you are making this under Windows as well). Only thing I notice your Makefile uses `src/` . Not sure if that has to be `src\` (I can't recall off the top of my head)

Comment: Yep I'm using cygwin on windows to compile everything

Comment: It turns out that the make file is compiling all the c files correctly but isn't compiling the asm file which is why it complains about a missing entry point but I'm not sure why it's skipping this file

Comment: @flabbyllama Make sure `_start` is a global symbol!

Comment: Might the problem be the fact that you're using `src/*.o` as your list of object files? That would only enumerate those object files which already exist, and when compiling an empty tree, it would find nothing.

Comment: @fuz in his code it was global. Dolda's comment is closer to the mark. He wasn't properly creating lists of files to assemble/compile/link. His assembler file wasn't being compiled to an object and thus not being linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to modify your `Makefile` to something like this:

```
CC = i686-elf-gcc
AS = i686-elf-as
LD = i686-elf-gcc
AS_FLAGS =
LD_FLAGS = -ffreestanding -nostdlib -lgcc -Tlinker.ld
CC_FLAGS = -c -std=gnu99 -ffreestanding -O2 -Wall -Wextra -I./include

C_FILES := $(wildcard src/*.c)
ASM_FILES := $(wildcard src/*.asm)
O_FILES := $(C_FILES:.c=.o) $(ASM_FILES:.asm=.o)
KERNEL_BIN := myos.bin

all: $(KERNEL_BIN)

clean:
        rm -f $(KERNEL_BIN) $(O_FILES)

$(KERNEL_BIN): $(O_FILES)
        $(LD) $(LD_FLAGS) -o $@ $^

%.o: %.c
        $(CC) $(CC_FLAGS) -o $@ $<

%.o: %.asm
        $(AS) $(AS_FLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

This `Makefile` is different in that we construct a list of ASM files and *C* files. I also cleaned up the `LD_FLAGS` a bit and added an extra rule to create `myos.bin` and to `clean` the object and bin files.

In your current code you'd have the Makefile variables with this in them after expansion:

```
C_FILES   = src/string.c src/tty.c src/kernel.c
ASM_FILES = src/boot.asm
O_FILES   = src/string.o src/tty.o src/kernel.o src/boot.o
```

`O_FILES` was derived from concatenating both file lists together and replacing the `.c` and `.asm` extensions with `.o`. This is the list of all the objects that need to be generated from their source files.

With *GNU Assembler* it is customary to use files with `.s` extensions (or `.S` if you want to use the *C* preprocessor) rather than `.asm`

---

The reason the `_start` label wasn't found is because the assembly files were not being processed. This means that `boot.asm` was not becoming `boot.o` and thus wasn't being linked at all.